# Atomic number $Z$

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, atoms, electronic-configuration, atomic-radius

If electrons were spin-$\frac {3}{2}$
instead of spin-$\frac {1}{2}$ ,

what would be the atomic
number $Z$ for the first noble gas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spin multiplicity will be $2S+1=4$. This means that the first atomic orbital can hold $4$ electrons with four different quantum numbers.

So, the atomic number for the first noble gas is $4$.